# Tight binding Hamiltonian in the k-space

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory, tight-binding

I want to find the band structure of this 2 dimensional lattice which isn't completely flat:

[image]

Using a tight binding model.And take unit cells as they are shown in the figure. And assuming that each site has only one atomic orbital and hopping is between nearest neighborhoods and next nearest neighbors(only for those wich are connected with blue line in the figure) with same amplitude and taking on-site energy equal to zero. My problem is to write the Hamiltonian in the reciprocal space. The result of my calculation, for example for the contribution of hopping between 1 and 5 (or between any two inner site in each unit cell) is 
$$ H_{12}=-t\sum_{\vec{k}}(|1,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 5,\vec{k} | + |5,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 1,\vec{k} |)$$

And for hopping between outer sites (for example 5 and 8) is:
$$ H_{58}=-t\sum_{\vec{k}} (e^{i \vec{k}.\vec{d_x}}|5,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 8,\vec{k} | + e^{-i \vec{k}.\vec{d_x}}|8,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 5,\vec{k} |)$$

Where $\vec{d_x}$ and $\vec{d_y}$ are vectors with length of the unit cell and directions along x and y axis.
But it seems that these relations are wrong. And $H_{15}$ must be :
$$H_{12}= -t\sum_{\vec{k}} (e^{i\vec{k}.\vec{h}}|1,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 5,\vec{k} | +e^{-i\vec{k}.\vec{h}} |5,\vec{k}\rangle \langle 1,\vec{k} |)$$
Where :
$$\vec{h}=\sqrt{2} \Delta (\hat{x} + \hat{y})$$
And $\Delta$ is thickness of lattice.
What's the problem,What am I missing ?
And what h